# negative R-squared for a test dataset in linear regression?

Tags: r, model, regression, linear-regression, lm

I am doing a simulation of a linear regression using artificial data and then calculate manually the RSE and R Square.  I do this for an in Sample dataset where the model is trained and then I test the model on an Out of Sample dataset.  The Out of Sample and In Sample data are drawn from the same normal distribution but with different seeds.  My numbers though when it comes to the out-of-Sample dataset do not make sense.  Could you please help me locate the bug?

```
set.seed(1)
z1 <- rnorm(100)
z2 <- z1 ^ 2
error <- rnorm(100, sd = 0.25)
y1 <- 1 + 2 * z1 + error
data1 <- data.table(y1, z1, z2)
model_quad <- lm(y1 ~ z1 + z2, data1)
model_lin <- lm(y1 ~ z1, data1)

confint(model_lin)
confint(model_quad)

summary(model_lin)
summary(model_quad)

ggplot(data1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z1, y = y1), color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z2, y = y1), color = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z1, y = y1), color = "blue", size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z2, y = y1), color = "red", size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z1, y = y1), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z2, y = y1), fill = "red", alpha = 0.1) 

set.seed(100)
z12 <- rnorm(100)
z22 <- z12 ^ 2
error2 <- rnorm(100, sd = 0.25)
y2 <- 1 + 2 * z12 + error2
data2 <- data.table(y2, z12, z22)

summary(model_lin)
summary(model_quad)

ggplot(data2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z12, y = y2), color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = z22, y = y2), color = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z12, y = y2), color = "blue", size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z22, y = y2), color = "red", size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z12, y = y2), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = lm, aes(x = z22, y = y2), fill = "red", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0.99, slope = 1.999, size = 2, color = "yellow", alpha = 0.3)


predictions_in_sample_linear <-  predict(model_lin, data1)
predictions_in_sample_quadratic <- predict(model_quad, data1)
predictions_out_of_sample_linear <-  predict(model_lin, data2)
predictions_out_of_sample_quadratic <- predict(model_quad, data2)
TSE_in_sample <- (y1 - mean(y1)) %*% (y1 - mean(y1))
RSE_in_sample_linear <- (predictions_in_sample_linear - y1)  %*% (predictions_in_sample_linear - y1) 
RSE_in_sample_quadratic <- (predictions_in_sample_quadratic - y1)  %*% (predictions_in_sample_quadratic - y1) 
R_Square_in_sample_linear <- (TSE_in_sample - RSE_in_sample_linear) / TSE_in_sample
R_Square_in_sample_quadratic<- (TSE_in_sample - RSE_in_sample_quadratic) / TSE_in_sample
TSE_out_of_sample <- (y2 - mean(y2)) %*% (y2 - mean(y2))
RSE_out_of_sample_linear <- (predictions_out_of_sample_linear - y2)  %*% (predictions_out_of_sample_linear - y2) 
RSE_out_of_sample_quadratic <- (predictions_out_of_sample_quadratic - y2)  %*% (predictions_out_of_sample_quadratic - y2) 
R_Square_out_of_sample_linear <- (TSE_out_of_sample - RSE_out_of_sample_linear) / TSE_out_of_sample
R_Square_out_of_sample_quadratic<- (TSE_out_of_sample - RSE_out_of_sample_quadratic) / TSE_out_of_sample

predictions_in_sample_linear 
predictions_in_sample_quadratic 
predictions_out_of_sample_linear 
predictions_out_of_sample_quadratic 
TSE_in_sample 
RSE_in_sample_linear 
RSE_in_sample_quadratic 
R_Square_in_sample_linear 
R_Square_in_sample_quadratic
TSE_out_of_sample 
RSE_out_of_sample_linear 
RSE_out_of_sample_quadratic 
R_Square_out_of_sample_linear 
R_Square_out_of_sample_quadratic
```

This code returns R_square in the Out of Sample data negative, which is absurd.

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long question but short answer. You should use

```
data2 <- data.frame(y1 = y2, z1 = z12, z2 = z22)
```

This gives

```
RSE_out_of_sample_linear
# 0.9902969

RSE_out_of_sample_quadratic
# 0.989241
```